# How to add logger in RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have written an RCP application. For that I want to add logging using log4j.

Can any one suggest any solution for it?

I already tried with [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclog/), but I am unable to use it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I've used the same article and got everything working. Can you specify exactly what didn't worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the Eclipse logging. It is decribed in the Eclipse Wiki: http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/EAS/Logging_and_Tracing

This way you have the advantage that the logging from the RCP platform and your own logging share the same logfiles. This makes it easier to correlate events in the log file(s).

If you are using E4 already it is easy to inject the log-service (i.e. you won't need an activator class for your plugin). The wiki reference above also describes how to do that.

Comment: Hello @Stefan thanks for the link. It works for me. But I do have one of questions as, 1. Can we give a project specific log file name here instead of using default log?

Comment: Hi @Mandy, I did not try that yet, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) jar file is already packaged as an OSGi bundle. Simple drop that into the plugins folder of your target platform (or into the Eclipse plugins folder if you're using that as your target) then add it as a dependency to your project plugin.xml.

Comment: I like to modify my question for more clarification. I had log4j jar with me. I want to create logger for my application. How to create it and how to use it within program. If I deliver this plug-in to user, where he can able to find the logged messages?

Comment: Have you created a log4j.properties file? Can you edit your question to include it's contents?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use  `org.osgi.service.log.LogService` to log all your messages and add `LogListener` to forward logs to any other custom logging you have ( log4j,slf4j...etc). In this way you dont loose any logs that RCP framework does.

Answer (score 0):

jar in your classpath and then you can create logger with this code

```
private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
```

and you can change log file location with the following entry of log4j.properties

> log4j.appender.file.File=${workspace_loc}/.metadata/MyLogFile.log

Answer (score 0):

1. Add log4j.jar in your project.
2. Add the reference in MANIFEST.MF.
   `Require-Bundle: org.apache.log4j;bundle-version="1.2.15"`
3. Add the reference in build.properties.

   bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
                  META-INF/,\
                  .,\
                   lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
4. Use the logger in .java files.

   PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
    LOGGER.debug("STARTING APPLICATION ..");

I found this tutorial helpful. Please check - [Add log4j in RCP](http://javacodingtutorial.blogspot.de/2016/02/add-log4j-to-rcp-application.html)

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me very well.

```html
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.ILog;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

import com.example.addresbook.util.PluginLogListener;



/**
 * The activator class controls the plug-in life cycle.
 * @author Iakov Senatov
 */
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {
 private static final String LOG4J_PROPERTIES = "META-INF/log4j.properties";
 private static final String LOG4J_FILE_PATTTERN = "%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n";
 private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Activator.class );
 public static final String PLUGIN_ID = "com.example.addresbook";
 final private List<PluginLogListener> pluginLogHooks = new ArrayList<PluginLogListener>();
 private static Activator plugin;
 
 
 
 /**
  * The constructor
  */
 public Activator() {
 }
 
 
 
 /*
  * (non-Javadoc)
  *
  * @see
  * org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext
  * )
  */
 @Override
 public void start(BundleContext context ) throws Exception {
  initLog4j(context );
  LOG.debug("start()" );
  super.start(context );
  plugin = this;
 }
 
 
 
 /**
  * Inits the log4j.
  *
  * @throws IOException
  */
 private void initLog4j(BundleContext context ) throws IOException {
  final String log4jfile = LOG4J_PROPERTIES;
  final URL confURL = getBundle().getEntry(log4jfile );
  //Define file appender with layout and output log file name
  final PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout(LOG4J_FILE_PATTTERN );
  final String logPath = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() + "logs"
      + File.separator + "addtBook.log";
  final RollingFileAppender fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, logPath );
  PropertyConfigurator.configure(FileLocator.toFileURL(confURL ).getFile() );
  LOG.debug("Logging using log4j and configuration " + FileLocator.toFileURL(confURL ).getFile() );
  Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fileAppender );
  hookPluginLoggers(context );
  LOG.info("contextInitialized()" );
  LOG.info("Log4j initialized with " + confURL );
 }
 
 
 
 // Hook all loaded bundles into the log4j framework
 private void hookPluginLoggers(final BundleContext context ) {
  for(final Bundle bundle : context.getBundles() ) {
   final ILog pluginLogger = Platform.getLog(bundle );
   pluginLogHooks.add(new PluginLogListener(pluginLogger, Logger.getLogger(bundle.getSymbolicName() ) ) );
   LOG.info("Added logging hook for bundle: " + bundle.getSymbolicName() );
  }
 }
 
 
 
 /*
  * (non-Javadoc)
  *
  * @see
  * org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext
  * )
  */
 @Override
 public void stop(BundleContext context ) throws Exception {
  LOG.debug("stop()" );
  plugin = null;
  super.stop(context );
 }
 
 
 
 /**
  * Returns the shared instance
  *
  * @return the shared instance
  */
 public static Activator getDefault() {
  LOG.debug("getDefault()" );
  return plugin;
 }
 
 
 
 /**
  * Returns an image descriptor for the image file at the given plug-in
  * relative path
  *
  * @param path the path
  * @return the image descriptor
  */
 public static ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor(String path ) {
  LOG.debug("getImageDescriptor()" );
  return imageDescriptorFromPlugin(PLUGIN_ID, path );
 }
}
```